# Swift - Programming UISwipeGestureRecognizer to separately control 2 objects

Tags: swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Brand new to Swift but am picking it up little by little. I have 2 objects that I want to control at the same time with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. I have it working for one object but need to be able to swipe on the left side of the screen and the right side to control the 2 objects separately. I'm guessing I can implement a statement that if swipe is less than this position control this object else control this one just not sure how to implement. This is what I'm using to control the one object.

```
self.swipeRightGesture.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleRightSwipe:"))
self.swipeRightGesture.direction = .Right
self.swipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(self.swipeRightGesture)

func handleRightSwipe(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if !self.isMoving && self.isMovingUp == true{
        self.leftobjectmoveright()
        self.isMoving = true
        self.isMoving = false
        self.isMovingUp = false

    }
}

func leftobjectmoveright() {

    self.leftobject.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(75,0)

}
```

Comment: Sorry. Was trying to be clear but realize now it's not as clear to someone else. I need to be able to swipe UP, Left, and Right for both object separately. I have those 3 working for the left object just need to get it working for the right object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And how do you intend the user to reflect which of the three gestures (up, left, and right) is for which object? Are you starting the gesture on top of the object? If that's the case, there are a couple of approaches.

The most logical approach, in my opinion, is to create a separate set of gestures for each object, and then in the gesture recognizer, you can look at `gesture.view` to identify which one resulted in the gesture recognizer's selector to be called. For example:

```
let leftObjectDownSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleDownSwipe:"))
leftObjectDownSwipe.direction = .Down
leftObject?.addGestureRecognizer(leftObjectDownSwipe)

let rightObjectDownSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleDownSwipe:"))
rightObjectDownSwipe.direction = .Down
rightObject?.addGestureRecognizer(rightObjectDownSwipe)
```

With a `handleDownSwipe` like so:

```
func handleDownSwipe(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.view == leftObject {
        println("swiped left one")
    } else if gesture.view == rightObject {
        println("swiped right one")
    }
}
```

Or, if the handling of the gestures for the two different objects were sufficiently different, you might just give them completely separate gesture handlers. It's just a question of how much common code there is in these two gesture handlers.

---

Alternatively, you could put the gesture recognizer on the superview that contains these two view objects:

```
let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleDownSwipe:"))
downSwipe.direction = .Down
view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
```

And then you could have the gesture recognizer look at the width of the view and compare that to the `locationInView`:

```
func handleDownSwipe(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.locationInView(gesture.view)
    if location.x < (gesture.view!.frame.size.width / 2.0) {
        println("swiped left side")
    } else {
        println("swiped right side")
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of having the screen basically split into two "boxes". So if the swipe was started to the left of some coordinate it would move the left object. If it was started to the right of some coordinate it would move the right object. That way you dont have to touch the object to move it. Just swipe within either one of those "boxes". Hopefully I'm starting to make sense and you're getting a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with. Just need something to kick start me. Not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: Put gesture recognizer on superview and then look at `locationInView`. See revised answer. Or actually add these two "boxes" that you talked about and use my original answer, only putting the gesture recognizers on the boxes rather than the visible view objects. Either way works.